# How to show header for today as selected in full calendar weekview

Tags: fullcalendar

[image]I want the header in Fullcalendar weeek view to be shown as selected for Today date. How can this be achieved?

I want the blue border to be present from top of Tuesday 21. I am able to achieve from the bottom of the cell but the same needs to shown from top.

Comment: I want to do this by applying css

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot of what do you want to achieve? It's hard to tell what do you need exactly. Thanks!